# API RESTful URL path for custom action

Tags: rest, api, url, restful-url

I have a budget entity...

At some point, the app lets you create a new budget for a client. Before saving the budget you have the option of generate a preview where the total amounts based on your selections are shown.

Those calculations are done in the server so I need to expose the appropriate endpoint, but I'm not sure what that endpoint should be.

I was thinking of `[GET] http://example.com/budgets/preview/` with the needed parameters sent along.

Is this correct? This will point to a `preview()` method in `budget` class.

And what about a preview for a budget that I already saved?

`[GET] http://example.com/budgets/{ID}/preview/`?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that REST is all about having multiple representations of a resource where required, so one of the first things to identify is what are the resources and if there are any relationships between them.

To me, it seems like you have the concept of a budget as a resource and a budgetPreview as a resource, and you would like the ability to retrieve either of them at a later date as well.

I'd suggest the following the URI'seems

[GET] http://example.com/budgetPreviews/generate

This will generate and return a budgetPreview on the server without storing it. IMO it doesn't seem clear in the API that route to creating a budgetPreview is nested under a budget. I also advocate slightly moving away from "all endpoints must be nouns" to favour business actions that one can preform on or with resources. If anyone ever argues, you can just change the generate to "generateRequest", since in effect you are passing a document to the server filled with values that represent your request to generate a budgetPreview. One assumption I make here is that the all the information required for the server to build the budgetPreview is passed along from the client in the GET request.

The one thing to be wary of here is you will need to include all of your information in the URI as query parameters since the value returned will be different based on the parameters. Passing values in the body of a GET and then giving that body semantic meaning (i.e creating a different resource based on values in the body) will break caching (if your doing any).

[GET] http://example.com/budgetPreviews

Return all of the existing stored budgetPreviews

[PUT] http://example.com/budgetPreviews/{GUID}

Using a put to create a resource here and allowing the client to determine the id means that the request to store the resource can be retried in the case of timeouts and allows for idempotency. At the same time you are storing a budget preview you could provide the Id of the budget in the parameters and link them.

[GET] http://example.com/budgets/{GUID}/budgetPreview

[GET] http://example.com/budgetPreviews/{GUID}

These are different URI's identifying the same resource and allow for different ways in the client to consume the budgetPreview

An extra point is not to confuse your underlying resource or implementation details such as which method gets called with what your public facing API looks like. Aim to have your public facing API be as suitable as possible for the client, and your representations that you return to focus on modelling the client contracts rather than what the underlying resources are persisted as.

Also, another thing that a wise person once told me is remember you have infinite URI's at your disposal so don't be afraid to create more when it gives your API clarity and your clients exactly what they want.

Answer (score 0):

Don't overload the URL segment after `/budgets` to contain either an ID or "preview". Instead, use

```
[GET]  /budgets/{id}
[POST] /budget-previews
       > returns a preview given the data in the body
[GET] /budget-previews/{id}
       > returns a preview given data on the server
```

Existing budgets can provide a link to their preview, while new budgets can request a preview. You can, if you choose, save the previews separately when you do the `POST /budget-previews`, and then possibly create a budget from a preview with `POST /budgets?previewId={}` (or put the preview id in the body of the `POST`). I would avoid using the budget id as the preview id, in case you decide later you want to save previews separately.

If there are and will be no other kinds of preview, consider using `/previews` instead of `budget-previews`.